# Вывод html элементов в ASP .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

при выводе строке вида `str="строка1 <br/> строка2 "` выводится строка целиком с отображением `<br/>`, т.е. html элемент представляется как текст и перевода строки нет. Как исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше содержание находится внутри строки с именем str

Вы можете использовать:

```
@Html.Raw(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы отобразить незакодированную информацию на экране мы можем воспользоваться методом `Html.Raw`, используемый для принудительного отображения необработанного текста

[Отображение данных модели в представлении](http://smarly.net/asp-net-mvc-4-in-action/high-speed-fundamentals/view-fundamentals/passing-data-to-views#text-16252)